# 32 bit Miniconda python 3.5 Matplotlib crash. Windows 7

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, crash, anaconda, miniconda

Plenty of posts similar to this but nothing quite as simple as this build that I have been able to find.

I am new to Python and trying to recreate MATLAB functionality, so i want pyplot obviously.

From scratch I installed as follows:

32 bit miniconda .exe
https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86.exe

pycharm 5.0 (also tried with 4.5.4)

pycharm interpreter = 3.5.0 at C:\Users\xxx.xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3.exe

run in pycharm terminal:

> conda install numpy    ...   y ...completed
>
> conda install scipy    ...   y ...completed
>
> conda install matplotlib    ...   y ...completed

after Pycharm finishes showing "indexing" at the bottom of the project window, i run:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

I can import numpy, matplotlib, and scipy now without any errors.

The code above brings up a pop up showing:

Python has stopped working
A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program.
*with options*
 - Close the Program
 - Debug the program

I get the same when running this as script in Python 3.5, or in Pycharm.

If i choose to close the program the window disappears and pycharm continues to run without showing a plot.

If i choose to Debug Microsoft Visual Studio is opened by default showing the following:

Unhandled exception at 0x5BD64A82 (libpng16.dll) in python.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0D000140.

*with options:* 
- Break
- Continue

Neither of these options seem to do much for me however I'm not familiar with VS.

I never see anything resembling a plot no matter what I do.

Any ideas? Am i missing something? I dont really want to go to Python 2.7 (as suggested elsewhere) as i have no need for backward compatibility, but will give it a go if thats the only fix...

Thanks in advance.

Pat.

Comment: What does `matplotlib.get_backend()` give?  Also try giving the full anacanda distrobution a try an/or I bringing this up on the anaconda mailing list.

Comment: 'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt print(plt.get_backend())' gives:

Qt4Agg

I have no idea what that means

Comment: Did `conda` install `pyqt` and `qt`?

Comment: @tcaswell yep i ran 'conda install pyqt' and 'conda install qt', both returned 'All requested packages already installed'.

Comment: Just ran this in the full anaconda environment and have the same failure

Comment: Ah, I missed this before, it looks like you have crossed versions of libpng.dll .  Try re-installing that?  Sorry, I know very little about windows and have about exhausted my understanding.  I would try removing _everything_ related to python and starting from scratch?